# Struts s:autocompleter tag onchange event

Tags: struts2, autocomplete

Is there a way to add an onchange event to the [s:autocompleter](http://struts.apache.org/2.0.6/docs/ajax-tags.html#AjaxTags-Autocompleter) tag in struts?
I need to call a javascript function when the selection changes.

Comment: There is an onchange property in many tags (Including the autocompleter). Does calling your javascript function not work from there?

Comment: @Quaternion no, it does not work.